Why is the innerHandleOp() function declared as external in EntryPoint in ERC-4337?
Looking at the code below, there is a comment that says "Must be declared "external" to open a call context, but it can only be called by handleOps.", but I'm not sure what exactly is meant by "open a call context" here. I understood that context is the message received from the paymaster during the validation phase, which is then passed back to the execution phase. Why does the function need to be executed as external specifically for this process?
/**
 * inner function to handle a UserOperation.
 * Must be declared "external" to open a call context, but it can only be called by handleOps. <- I don't understand the phrase open a call context
 */
function innerHandleOp(bytes memory callData, UserOpInfo memory opInfo, bytes calldata context) external returns (uint256 actualGasCost) {
    uint256 preGas = gasleft();
    require(msg.sender == address(this), "AA92 internal call only");
    MemoryUserOp memory mUserOp = opInfo.mUserOp;

    uint callGasLimit = mUserOp.callGasLimit;
unchecked {
    // handleOps was called with gas limit too low. abort entire bundle.
    if (gasleft() < callGasLimit + mUserOp.verificationGasLimit + 5000) {
        assembly {
            mstore(0, INNER_OUT_OF_GAS)
            revert(0, 32)
        }
    }
}

    IPaymaster.PostOpMode mode = IPaymaster.PostOpMode.opSucceeded;
    if (callData.length > 0) {
        bool success = Exec.call(mUserOp.sender, 0, callData, callGasLimit);
        if (!success) {
            bytes memory result = Exec.getReturnData(REVERT_REASON_MAX_LEN);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                emit UserOperationRevertReason(opInfo.userOpHash, mUserOp.sender, mUserOp.nonce, result);
            }
            mode = IPaymaster.PostOpMode.opReverted;
        }
    }

unchecked {
    uint256 actualGas = preGas - gasleft() + opInfo.preOpGas;
    //note: opIndex is ignored (relevant only if mode==postOpReverted, which is only possible outside of innerHandleOp)
    return _handlePostOp(0, mode, opInfo, context, actualGas);
}
}

